# Can I order the joined entities in Doctrine2?

Tags: doctrine-orm

Say I've got two entities: Entity1 and Entity2. Entity1 has many Entity2's.

Can I make a query in doctrine2 to select all the Entity1 with their inner Entity2s ordered by some field?

```
//I'd need this query but with the Entity2s ordered within each Entity1
SELECT e1,e2 FROM 'BundleName:Entity1' e1 JOIN e.entity2s e2;
```

I'd need to do this without the @OrderBy("somefield") annotation in Entity2.

Comment: You can just add a `ORDER BY` clause to your DQL. ie. `SELECT e1,e2 FROM 'BundleName:Entity1' e1 JOIN e.entity1 e2 ORDER BY e1.somefield`

Comment: What I want to order are not the entity1 objects, I want to order the entity2 objects that will be inside each entity1 object

Comment: You can use multiple fields to order by. `ORDER BY e1.uniqueid, e2.somefield`.

Comment: Ei, I'll check that out tomorrow ! I'm off work.

Comment: Well, it did work ! I can't believe it was that easy.
Post it as an answer and I'll check it as best answer.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a `ORDER BY` clause to the DQL same as you would do with native SQL. When you want to order multiple fields you can simply seperate them with a comma. In your case you want to order entity1 first by their unique identifier, next you sort by a field of entity 2.

Your final query would look something like this:

```
SELECT e1,e2 FROM 'BundleName:Entity1' e1 JOIN e.entity2s e2 ORDER BY e1.id, e2.somefield;
```